# laravel database query Does `where` always need `first()`?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am new to laravel and confused about some query methods.

`find($id)` is useful and returns a nice array, but sometimes I need to select by other fields rather than `id`.

The Laravel document said I could use `where('field', '=', 'value')` and return a bunch of data, which is fine.

What I can't understand is why I need to add `->first()` every time, even if I am pretty sure there is only one single row matches the query.

Answer (score 6):

It goes like this:

```php
$query->where(..)->orderBy(..)->limit(..) etc.
// you can chain the methods as you like, and finally you need one of:

->get($columns); // returns Eloquent Collection of Models or array of stdObjects
->first($columns); // returns single row (Eloquent Model or stdClass)
->find($id); // returns single row (Eloquent Model or stdClass)
->find($ids); // returns Eloquent Collection
// those are examples, there are many more like firstOrFail, findMany etc, check the api

$columns is an array of fields to retrieve, default array('*')
$id is a single primary key value
$ids is an array of PKs, this works in find method only for Eloquent Builder

// or aggregate functions:
->count()
->avg()
->aggregate()
// just examples here too
```

So the method depends on what you want to retrieve (array/collection or single object)

Also the return objects depend on the builder you are using (Eloquent Builder or Query Builder):

```
User::get(); // Eloquent Colleciton
DB::table('users')->get(); // array of stdObjects
```

Answer (score 0):

> even if I am pretty sure there is only one single row matches the query.

Well Laravel cant read your mind - so you need to tell it what you want to do.

You can do either

```
User::where('field', '=', 'value')->get()
```

Which will return all objects that match that search. Sometimes it might be one, but sometimes it might be 2 or 3...

If you are sure there is only one (or you only want the first) you can do

```
User::where('field', '=', 'value')->first()
```

Answer (score 0):

- get() returns an array of objects (multiple rows)

while

- first() returns a single object (a row)

You can of course use get() when you know it will return only one row, but you need to keep that in mind when addressing the result:

> using get()

```
$rez = \DB::table('table')->where('sec_id','=','5')->get();
//will return one row in an array with one item, but will be addressed as:
$myfieldvalue = $rez[0]->fieldname;
```

---

> using first()

```
$rez = \DB::table('table')->where('sec_id','=','5')->first();
// will also return one row but without the array, so
$myfieldvalue = $rez->fieldname;
```

So it depends on how you want to access the result of the query: as an object or as an array, and also depends on what "you know" the query will return.

- first() is the equivalent of LIMIT 1 at the end of your SELECT statement. Even if your query would return multiple rows, if you use first() it will only return the first row